# Attribute routing number of parameters with 404 not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

I use AttributeRouting to set specific route for my ActionResult. I got an 404 page not found when I have this configuration:

```
[GET("Tender/SubmitBid/{id}/{bidId}")]
public ActionResult SubmitBid(string id, string bidId)
{ 
 ...
 return View(model);
}

@using ("SubmitBid", "Tender", new { id = Model.TenderId, bidId = Model.BidId }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
 ...    
 <button type="submit">Save</button>
}

// 404 not found
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitBid(BidViewModel model)
{
 ...
}
```

I installed a url sniffer to see the url trigger the 404 page not found and I got this: http.../Tender/SubmitBid/1/0

It supposed to be working... but I have to remove the latest parameters to reach the ActionResult and I don't know why.

Thank you for your help,

Karine

**Edit**
If I remove the attribute [GET("Tender/SubmitBid/{id}/{bidId}")] the page is accessible for the POST request. But the url is like http...//Tender/SubmitBid/1?bidId=0

Comment: Which request is not working. The `GET` or `POST`?

Comment: Can you show the post request and the `BidViewModel` class?

Comment: Hi Henk, I can but I don't think it will be usefull. BidViewModel has public int BidId and public int TenderId with some other information and all of them use an Html.HiddenFor to store the value between the GET and the POST. And the POST request is in the main content: // 404 not found [HttpPost] public ActionResult... Like I said in the Edit section if I only use one parameter instead of two the ActionResult will be triggered. I can reproduce the same thing each time I have two parameters or more to pass.

Comment: Why do you want query string parameters in the POST url? The point of a POST is that you don't have them. It's working with one parameter because it uses the default route. (`{controller}/{action}/{id}`)

Comment: I'm sorry my sentence is maybe not clear. I do not want to receive those parameters in the POST url. If you refer to the code I pasted for you, you can see that the parameters is for GET request only. The POST request receive a BidViewModel and NOT the parameters... So once all this is clear, it's currently the POST request that it not accessible when I submit the form. I get a 404 page not found and I don't know why.

Comment: I see, but in the `Html.BeginForm()` method, you are telling MVC to post to an url with the `id` and `bidId` parameters, which doesn't exist. Remove `new { id = Model.TenderId, bidId = Model.BidId },` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need the query string parameters since they exist in the `BidViewModel` you post. The point of a POST request is that you don't have query string parameters.

I think you have to use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) of the [`Html.BeginForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitBid", "Tender", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BidId)

    // Other properties..

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

Now it will post to `http:localhost/Tender/SubmitBid` with the properties of `BidViewModel` as post values, which contain `Id` and `BidId`. The signature of the POST action can stay the same:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitBid(BidViewModel model)
{
    string id = model.Id;
    string bidId =  model.bidId;

    // ...
}
```

It's also possible that AttributeRouting causes this issue. Can you try this with native ASP.NET MVC routing? You could use this specific route for submitting bids:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SubmitBid",
    url: "Tender/SubmitBid/{id}/{bidId}/",
    defaults: new 
                { 
                    controller = "Tender", 
                    action = "SubmitBid", 
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                    bidId = UrlParameter.Optional 
                });
```

Comment: Sorry my code is already like that and I get the 404 page not found. Could you just put the GET request to see how you handle it please with the same number of parameters?

Comment: @Karine your code is not like that, because you used the overload with routeValues, which causes your form to post to the wrong url. Compare my `Html.BeginForm()` method with yours.

Comment: Yeah you right, I just try the overload and unfortunately I got the same thing =(

Comment: @Karine to which URL are you posting now? Can you capture the POST request with Firebug or Fiddler and show it?

Comment: The html form tag is: <form action="/Tender/SubmitBid/1/0" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">. Exactly the same thing with the other overload =( If I remove the bidId parameter from the GET request the form will be <form... action="/Tender/SubmitBid/1></form> and this one will work... I don't know why..

Comment: @Karine it should be `<form action="/Tender/SubmitBid" ..>` _without_ the `id` and `bidId` parameters. Perhaps you need to add a route like `[POST("Tender/SubmitBid/")]` to the post method?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40216/discussion-between-karine-and-henk-mollema)

Comment: Finally, it was AttributeRouting that causes this issue. Thank you Henk!!